# NGINX - proxying to a different Wordpress site while retaining URL

Tags: php, nginx, wordpress

I currently have two WORDPRESS websites sitting behind an NGINX proxy cache:

htxtp://local.example.com
htxtp://local.example.org

I want to access a URL from the first site but serve it from the second site whilst not losing the URL structure of the first (to allow example.org to see the example.com cookies).

For example:

I want:

htxtp://local.example.com/somepage/

To proxy the page built at:

htxtp://local.example.org/somepage/

BUT I don't want the URL to BE htxtp://local.example.org.

My NGINX config is as follows:

```
server {
   listen      80;
   server_name local.example.com;
   access_log  logs/local.example.com.access.log;
   error_log   logs/local.example.com.error.log;


    location /somepage {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080;

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            local.example.org;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            local.example.com;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? I am trying to work out where the actual redirect is happening.

Comment: You have three domain names in your questions which is quite confusing. Also, can you say more clearly what is actually happening i.e. are you saying someone goes to one domain, but they're being redirected to another domain?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

> to allow website2.com to see the website1.com cookies

You can't, because of browser security.

The intro is interesting : http://www.innovativephp.com/sharing-cookies-across-multiple-domains-hosted-on-different-servers/

> Assume you have a sites called www.example.com and www.example.com hosted on same server. Even though both sites are on same server, domain names are different hence you will see that the cookies will not be working in another top domain. So we cannot use cookies between those 2 sites. But if you have site called www.example.com and subdomains called www.app.example.com, www.demo.example.com, you can set cookie values for all 3 domains and communicate between each domain.

Comment: Hence the need for me to proxy - as long as website2's content is visible via a website1 URL the cookies should be shareable regardless of anything else. The browser shouldn't be aware of WHERE the page being served is and therefore browser security doesn't come into it. Ignore the cookie side of it - I just need to get the NGINX/Wordpress configuration to work without changing the URL.

Comment: you can try `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/website2/;` 
(if it doesn't help, please answer @Danack comment)

Answer (score 0):

Try passing location htxtp://local.example.com/somepage/ to .org version using proxy_pass:

```
server { #local.example.com server block 
server_name local.example.com;
   location /somepage {
     proxy_pass http://local.example.org;
   }
}
```